# How to get entry text and property value in agenda?

Tags: org-mode, org-agenda, point, marker

What is the lisp function to get some entry text (excluding descendant items) for the highlighted item in the org-agenda?

`org-agenda-get-some-entry-text` seems to be promising. I have called it like this via a key in `org-agenda-mode-map`:

```
(org-agenda-get-some-entry-text (point-marker) 6)
```

but it always returns empty string and no error. What gives?

Also, there is a function to set an entry property in Agenda, `org-agenda-set-property`. Is there a counterpart for **getting** a property?

Is there anything like `org-agenda-get-property` out there?

Comment: This is really two questions.  It would be better to edit this question to include only one and ask the other separately.

Comment: You might find this useful: http://orgmode.org/manual/Using-the-property-API.html